# Error in a procedure while preparing to execute a query

Tags: sql-server

I got a error message in my procedure like

> (-3706) Syntax error: something was expected between the word 'DBO' and '.'.

I don't understand why?

This is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PS_DIM_FILMS]
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO FILMS.DBO.[T_DIM_FILMS]
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENQUERY(linked_server,
          'SELECT 
            REG.CODE_FILMS, REG.NAME_FILMS, 
            DEP.CODE_SERIES, DEP.NAME_SERIES
           FROM SERV.DBO.T_FILMS REG
           INNER JOIN SERV.DBO.T_EXCEL_SERIES DEP 
           ON DEP.CODE_SERIES = REG.CODE_FILMS')
END
```

Comment: That is not an error that SQL Server can issue. Double check that you're working with the database engine you think you are. For example, it's quite possible the linked server that's being connected to isn't a SQL Server and doesn't accept the syntax you gave it.

Comment: Seems specific to Teradata Database.